# How to return QStringList from a dialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have some Dialog class via which I select files and/or directories. Within this dialog there is a fnc called okBtn_clicked and in this fnc I'm getting QModelIndexes and via them I'm able to create QStringList of picked files. But how to return them after this dialog is closed?
EDIT:

```
QModelIndexList Dir_File_Select::okBtn_clicked_()
{
    accept();
    return view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which Qt class do you use to select/browse files?

Comment: It depends where and how you're using it. Perhaps you can still use the dialog object. Only when it's destroyed it becomes invalid.

Comment: @NickDandoulakis I was rather thinking of returning result just like QFileDialog::getFiles returns selected files.

Comment: @smallB: Post the relevant code. Also post a more clearer question.

Comment: @smallB: That is all you can show us? Where is the event binding code? and type informations of the objects?

Comment: After three years since this question I find myself in similar soup. Thanx to stack overflow and the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still access the dialog after it is closed except it's destructor has been called. So the easiest approach would be to add a public function that will return the `QStringList` you want.

```
QStringList getList()
{
    QStringList list;
    // populate it
    return list;
}
```

In your main application you should just connect the `accepted` signal of the dialog with a slot that handles it and retrieves the string list.

```
connect(dialog, SINGAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(dialogAccepted()));

void dialogAccepted()
{
   QStringList list = dialog->getList();
   // do whatever you want with it
}
```

**Another** option is to create a signal in your dialog with a `QStringList` as argument and emit it before the `accept`

```
void onOKButtonClicked()
{
    QStringList list = createList(); // Construct a QStringList
    emit myStringListSignal(list);
    accept();
}
```

Again you have to connect this signal with a slot that handles the `QStringList`

```
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(myStringListSignal(QStringList)), this, SLOT(handleDialogStringList(QStringList)));

void handleDialogStringList(QStringList list)
{
   // do whatever you want with the list
}
```

Your ok button slot should not return anything since this is handled internally by `Qt`.

Answer (score 1):

Do something similar to QFileDialog.

```
// Pseudocode

class Dir_File_Select {
private:
    QStringList filenames;

[...]

void Dir_File_Select::okBtn_clicked_()
{
    accept();

    //return view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    update filenames
}

QStringList Dir_File_Select::getFiles()
{
    return filenames;
}
```

and in some other class

```
void Class::foo() {
    Dir_File_Selec dlg;

    dlg.show();
    dlg.getFiles(); // <--
}
```